# Why does Membership model does not get created with this implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, when I click "Join" (below), the Membership model does not get created. Instead it just moves to index.html.erb in membership and nothing else happens. What could I be doing wrong? I'd really appreciate help. The error message (not really error) in the terminal is at the bottom.

Places index.html.erb:

```
<% @places.each do |p| %> 
    <%= p.name %>
    <%= link_to "Join", memberships_path(place_id: p.id, user_id: current_user.id, 'membership[place_id]': true), data: { turbo_method: "post" }, class:'', style:'' %>
<% end %>
```

Membership controller:

```
  def create
    @membership = Membership.new(membership_params)
    if @membership.save
      flash[:notice] = ""
      redirect_back fallback_location: places_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add membership."
      redirect_back fallback_location: places_path
    end
  end

    def membership_params
        params.require(:membership).permit(place_id: params[:place_id], user_id: current_user.id )
    end
```

Membership.rb:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :place
end
```

Place.rb:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :places, through: :memberships

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :places
  resources :users
  resources :memberships

  resources :places do
    resources :memberships
  end

  resources :users do 
    resources :memberships 
  end
```

Terminal message:

```
Started POST "/memberships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-04-18 17:32:54 -0400
Processing by MembershipsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"membership"=>{"place_id"=>"true"}, "place_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1"}
  Place Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:16:in `create'
  Place Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places" WHERE "places"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:16:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:16:in `create'
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Comment: Are you watching your `log/development.log` or `rails s` output for any details as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Look closely at `params` as you're expecting them to be under `membership` which they are not as supplied in your `path` parameters.

Comment: @tadman, thank you. I see this in terminal: ```Started GET "/memberships?place_id=1&user_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-04-18 17:06:51 -0400
Processing by MembershipsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"place_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering memberships/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered memberships/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 7)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.7ms | Allocations: 2400)```

Comment: See where the parameters are? Top-level. You also seem to have a Rails UJS issue if this is coming through as a GET request. Check that `application.js` is loading correctly.

Comment: @tadman I see thank you. Rails 7 seems to have replaced UJS with turbo -- can I use that instead? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality

Comment: Turbo is the new UJS solution for Rails, yes, but if it isn't working correctly you'll find all kinds of stuff is weirdly broken, exactly like you have here. Once you get that sorted out I think you'll be good.

Comment: @tadman I changed the method to turbo like ```data: { turbo_method: "post" }```. I now get this error: ```ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: membership):
  
app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:33:in `membership_params'
app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb:15:in `create'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-04-18 17:22:43 -0400
```

Comment: I've told you a few times, so please, do read carefully: These parameters are *top level* and not nested like your strong params is declaring.

Comment: tadman's comment about top-level params seem correct.

You can: 
1. switch to `button_to` and use form params to get the nesting easily - you want a POST anyway.
2. use `link_to` with arguments like: `<%= link_to "Join", memberships_path(membership: { place_id: p.id, user_id: current_user.id, 'membership[place_id]': true}), data: { turbo_method: "post" }, class:'', style:'' %>` (note the nesting!)
3. alt without URL helper: `<%= link_to "Join", action: :create, controller: 'memberships', membership: { place_id: p.id, user_id: current_user.id, 'membership[place_id]': true} %>`

Answer (score 0):

Because in your case, the arguments to `permit` should just be a list of keys and not a hash. And your requested params are not nested below a `:membership` key, but directly in the params' root. Change

```
params.require(:membership).permit(place_id: params[:place_id], user_id: current_user.id )
```

to

```
params.permit(:place_id, :user_id)
```

Additionally: For security reasons, I suggest not passing the current_user's id to the controller like that because people could change the values.

Instead, I suggest changing the strong params to:

```
def membership_params
  params.permit(:place_id)
end
```

and the `create` method to

```
def create
  @membership = current_user.memberships.build(membership_params)
    if @membership.save
  # ...
```

And then there seems to be an issue with your JavaScript setup because even with the `data_method: :post` the request is still recognized as `get`. I recommend having a look at [Working with JavaScript in Rails in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality) and fixing the setup.

Comment: Thank you, spickermann! I made the change but the problem for the moment persists.

Comment: UJS. Don't forget that part.